# How to call http triggered azure function from timer triggered azure function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger, timer-trigger

There is a timer function, which in the middle of its work should call the http triggered (post request) function. How to do it? Will Durable function - chaining pattern help? How to pass parameters (in requestBody) to the called function?
p.s. I apologize if I expressed myself illiterately in this matter.

Investigated the implementation of the chaining pattern. In the examples there was only a function of type Activity Trigger.

Comment: Just create an HttpClient and call the function.

Comment: ^^ "Create" as in: Have one injected.

Comment: Are they in the same function app? Also, is it C# script or compiled from VS/VS Code? I ask because I don’t think you’re seeing the forest for the trees and I’ll have a better way to do it depending on your answer.

Comment: these two functions are in different function app. I use .NET 6.0 (c#) to implement azure functions.

Answer (score 0):

How to do it? - You will submit a [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=net-7.0) from the timer triggered function to the http triggered function.

Will Durable function - chaining pattern help? - Probably not, nothing you have mentioned so far in your problem statement leads me to believe that changing your pattern will address any of your concerns.

How to pass parameters (in requestBody) to the called function?  - The documentation  for webrequest provides some [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.method?view=net-7.0#examples)

Answer (score 0):

As @Oxymoron suggested, you have to use Web Request Object to Post the Http Trigger URL/Function and you can use one of the durable functions patterns to call the http trigger function from the timer trigger. and I followed @Thiago Custodio [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60552849/17623802) as below:

```cs
    namespace FunctionApp45
    {
        public class Function1
        {
            [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    
                var url = "https://www.google.co.in/";
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var htmlrawdata = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    log.LogInformation(htmlrawdata);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please suggest how should I implement authorization so that I can call a function from azure?
In the example you refer to, a local call occurs.

Comment: Check this SO #[75181464](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75181464/16630138) regarding implementation of security like Authorization on Azure Functions